# Overlapping css rectangles

Tags: html, css

So my goal here is to create 5 rectangles next to each other that are centered left, right, up, and down no matter how you re-size the browser.

```
<body>
    <div id="test1"></div>
    <div id="test2"></div>
    <div id="test3"></div>
    <div id="test4"></div>
    <div id="test5"></div>
</body>

#test1 {
    background-color:blue;
    width:200px;
    height:40px;
    margin:auto;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0; left: 0; bottom: 0; right: 0;
    float:left;
}

#test2 {
    background-color:black;
    width:200px;
    height:40px;
    margin:auto;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0; left: 0; bottom: 0; right: 25%;
    float:left;
}

#test3 {
    background-color:gray;
    width:200px;
    height:40px;
    margin:auto;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0; left: 25%; bottom: 0; right: 0;
    float:left;
}

#test4 {
    background-color:yellow;
    width:200px;
    height:40px;
    margin:auto;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0; left: 50%; bottom: 0; right: 0;
    float:left;
}
#test5{
    background-color:orange;
    width:200px;
    height:40px;
    margin:auto;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0; left: 0; bottom: 0; right: 50%;
    float:left;
}
```

This is the code I have so far and it almost works. But the rectangles start to overlap at a certain browser window width. I thought it would work to change the width to a percentage on each rectangle but if they are all at the same percentage they are just sitting on top of each other. Thanks in advance hopes someone can help me understand this a bit more.

[What it looks like with maximized browser](http://prntscr.com/2jed6k)

[What I wand to avoid when the browser gets too small](http://prntscr.com/2jedxa)

Comment: Never combine `float` with `position:absolute` - it's nonsense.

Comment: Forgot to remove those lines after I found that out. Didn't change anything so that's probably why I forgot. Fixed.

Comment: Your elements are going to overlap if you give them absolute widths and heights.  You have to give them min-width/max-widths and things like that.  I would suggest changing all of your widths to max-width and give all of your elements a percentage.

Comment: [Here's an incredibly cleaned up set of base code](http://jsfiddle.net/Curry/Drqx3/).

Comment: Also, please elaborate more precisely on the intended result when the browser becomes small.

Comment: I added links to be more specific on the issue.

Comment: If you provide a `top`, don't set a numerical value for `bottom`, and if you provide a `left`, don't provide a numerical value for `right`. Instead, set the value to `auto` to indicate you don't need that value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zsaat14/dF48g/8/) demonstrating my solution.  Basically, I added a container for your boxes, centered that, and then set the boxes to 20% of the container's width.

**The HTML:**

```
<body>
    <div id="container">
        <div id="test1"></div>
        <div id="test2"></div>
        <div id="test3"></div>
        <div id="test4"></div>
       <div id="test5"></div>
    </div>
</body>
```

**The CSS:**

```
#container{
    width: 80%;
    position:fixed;
    top:45%;
    left:10%;
    padding: 0;
    height: 40px;
}
#test1 {
    background-color:blue;
    width:20%;
    height:40px;
    margin:auto;
    float:left;
}
#test2 {
    background-color:black;
    width:20%;
    height:40px;
    margin:auto;
    float:left;
}
#test3 {
    background-color:gray;
    width:20%;
    height:40px;
    margin:auto;
    float:left;
}
#test4 {
    background-color:yellow;
    width:20%;
    height:40px;
    margin:auto;
    float:left;
}
#test5{
    background-color:orange;
    width:20%;
    height:40px;
    margin:auto;
    float:left;
}
```

Comment: This is great how would I add a set space between each of them?

Comment: try dispatch the 20% width  together with width and margin : http://jsfiddle.net/dF48g/9/ or http://jsfiddle.net/dF48g/10/

Answer (score 0):

Let me start with the [working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/eXhX4/), explanation below:

First, wrap your divs in a main div, and to make things simple, I gave all the child divs a common class:

```
<div id="main">
    <div class = "box" id = "test1">
    </div>

    <div class = "box" id = "test2">
    </div>

    <div class = "box" id = "test3">
    </div>

    <div class = "box" id = "test4">
    </div>

    <div class = "box" id = "test5">    
    </div>    
</div>
```

Now we need the main div to do two things, first, be 100% wide, second, have the same height as width, so we add the following css:

```
#main {
    width: 100%;
    position: relative; /* for absolutely positioned children */
}

#main:before {
    content: "";
    display: block;
    padding-top: 100%;  /* 1:1 ratio */
}
```

Then we give the common style to the boxes:

```
.box {
    width: 33%;
    height: 33%;
    position: absolute;
    margin: auto;
}
```

Now we set up the child elements (I might have changes the colors, oops)

```
#test1{
    background-color: blue;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
}

#test2{
    background-color: black;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
}
#test3{
    background-color: green;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
}
#test4{
    background-color: red;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
}
#test5{
    background-color: purple;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
}
```

And there you go, have fun.